# My fields complete itselves

Tags: html, symfony, input, autocomplete, passwords

good afternoon,

i'm, at the moment, programming a web site with Symfony2.
I use a form and into this form there are some input type="text"
and two input type="password".
I'm encountering a problem using this form, indeed the password and the neighboor input complete itselves, by using my own name and my password. 
The thing is that those inputs shouldn't be allowed to do this, a thing even stranger is that the input in which my name is put is not even a login input, it is called "inpCity".

I'm not sure if what i'm saying is clear for you, but this is really embarassing. I don't want it to autocomplete, i put the autocomplete attribute to off, but it just hides the value of the field.

Any idea about this ?

This is the first time it happens, while i used to create 3 others website (without Symfony)

PS : sorry for my english, this is not my main language

Answer (score 0):

I think it's built-in feature of browser but suggestions are based on the name of input field.

How did you override `getName()` of your form type? That "name" is prefixed to you field names, for example:

- `getName()` returns "my_form"
- input name is `email`
- your field will be named `my_form_email`

So, inspect you `HTML` and find how input name was generated...

Comment: Thanks for your answer,
i already looked at this, and this is how the name is generated : 

"myname_mybundle_mystuff".

Could this be the problem ?

Comment: This could could only pose a problem if you name **all** you apps and forms like that :) So, no, I don't think it's a problem. You mentioned you have put `autocomplete="off"`? I heard you need to specify it on both `input` AND `form`...

Comment: Ohh i see, i'll try it soon, thanks, i hope it will work